# Download different pdf depending on table row

Tags: html, database, wordpress

I have a wordpress page where depending on username it displays some laws applied to that user. I store these laws in a table in the wp database and the table has these columns: Id, law, description , username. The law and description columns are type VARCHAR.

My first issue is that every law can be applied to many users, so this means that this table will have too many rows the way it is created, because it will have the same law and description in multiple rows with just different username. Right now this table has only a few rows, so it's not a big deal yet, but I have to change this in the future. Is there a way to optimize this? Do i have to create another table?

My second issue is that i also need to add a functionality when the user clicks on one of his laws, a pdf related to this specific law is downloaded. Do I need an extra column in my table, say pdfId? Can someone offer some thoughts on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in the wordpress way to do this you could use a Custom Post Type (CPT) for laws, and link each record of the wp_post table with wp_postmeta records to hold the law data.

The pdfs can be uploaded into media library, and the url held in the wp_postmeta linked to the corresponding law. If the number of pdfs linked to a single law is only a few, you can use an array and serialize it as a postmenta value. Otherwise you may think of an additional CPT to link each law with each pdf.

Finally you can have another CPT (UserLaw for example) to link users and the laws that apply to them. In the postmeta for these records you would have the user's id and the id of the law that applies. And one entry in the wp_postmeta for ever law that applies to a sigle user.

Alertantively, as in the case of the pdfs, if each user will have only a small number of laws you can have only 1 postmeta entry for each UserLaw post where the law ids that apply are kept in an arry which is serialized as a value in the postmeta table.